# Transform a dataframe by counting the occurrences of a number in each row

Tags: r, dataframe, transform, apply

So I have this dataframe of 100,000 rows and 7 columns. Each of the columns is a randomly generated number. Here is how I made that dataframe:

```
dataframe <-  t(replicate(100000,sample(1:8,7)))
```

What I need help with is possibly applying a function or making a new dataframe that counts the occurrences of 2,3,5, or other numbers and displays that number in a row. So for example, If I have the dataframe:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    1    4    6    2    8    3    7
 [2,]    7    2    6    3    5    8    1
 [3,]    6    4    7    5    8    2    3
```

I would like it to be transformed into:

```
     "2""3""5""other"
[1,]  1  1  0    5
[2,]  1  1  1    4
[3,]  1  1  1    4
```

The label for each column isn't very important, but it would be nice to implement something like that too.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Base R option with `apply` :

For each row turn the values to `'other'` which is not 2, 3, or 5. Count the number of each value using `table`.

```
keep_values <- c(2, 3, 5)

t(apply(dataframe, 1, function(x) {
  table(factor(replace(x, !x %in% keep_values, 'other'),c(keep_values, 'other')))
}))

#     2 3 5 other
#[1,] 1 1 1     4
#[2,] 1 1 1     4
#[3,] 0 1 1     5
#[4,] 1 1 1     4
#[5,] 1 1 1     4
#[6,] 1 0 1     5
#...
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
dataframe <-  t(replicate(100000,sample(1:8,7)))
head(dataframe)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    7    8    3    6    2    4    5
#[2,]    3    5    4    1    2    8    6
#[3,]    5    3    7    1    4    8    6
#[4,]    5    3    2    6    1    8    4
#[5,]    4    6    1    3    5    7    2
#[6,]    7    2    5    1    6    8    4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with the tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr);library(purrr);
dataframe %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(map_dfc(list(Equal2 = 2,
                      Equal3 = 3,
                      Equal5 =5),~ rowSums(cur_data() == .x)),
         Other = sum(!str_detect(names(cur_data()),"Equal")) - rowSums(cbind(Equal2,Equal3,Equal5)))
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 Equal2 Equal3 Equal5 Other
#1   1  8  3  4  6  5  7      0      1      1     5
#2   3  4  1  5  2  6  8      1      1      1     4
#3   4  2  6  3  7  5  1      1      1      1     4
#4   2  3  5  1  8  7  6      1      1      1     4
```

Or with base R:

```
dataframe <- as.data.frame(dataframe)
IntCols <- sapply(list(Equal2 = 2, Equal3 = 3, Equal5 =5), 
                  function(x)rowSums(dataframe == x))
Other <- ncol(dataframe) - rowSums(IntCols)
cbind(dataframe,IntCols,Other)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 Equal2 Equal3 Equal5 Other
#1   1  8  3  4  6  5  7      0      1      1     5
#2   3  4  1  5  2  6  8      1      1      1     4
#3   4  2  6  3  7  5  1      1      1      1     4
#4   2  3  5  1  8  7  6      1      1      1     4
```

Comment: Thank you dear Mr. Campbell, your solution taught me a valuable lesson.